# sqlsrv only showing most recent row entries

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have an SQL command which is meant to display all users and all actions.
But what is actually happening is it is only showing the most recent row entries of a user, and not all entries.

My SQL is;

```
$stmt=

"
SELECT *
 FROM Actions
 FULL OUTER JOIN Users
 ON Actions.userID=Users.id;
";  


$query = sqlsrv_query($link,$stmt); 
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
```

I am then outputting it in a table as;

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>'; 
    ...
}
```

Would appreciate any advice.

--

Desired Result:

```
ID  |  USER  |  ACTION  |  TIME

1     Alpha    Logged-in   00:00

2     Bravo    Pswd Change 00:00

1     Alpha    Logged-out  00:01
```

--

Actual:

```
ID  |  USER  |  ACTION  |  TIME

2     Bravo    Pswd Change 00:00

1     Alpha    Logged-out  00:01
```

Comment: Your query would not have the behavior you describe.  Can you edit your question with sample data as well as desired and actual results?

Comment: Agreeing with @GordonLinoff, your SQL looks to be correct.  That will return all rows from both tables, joining them where possible, leaving NULLS where no join is possible.  If you're only getting 1 row per user, my first suspicion is something in the code responsible for displaying the results on the front end.  If you run your query directly in SQL, do you get the proper results?

Comment: I have added desired / actual results. And yes, if I query the DB direct I get the correct result

Comment: something is missing, please add the tables?

Comment: This is not SQL Server issue. You must be doing this wrong on the PHP processing/displaying side if a query ran on database directly is providing you with correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this:

```
$query = sqlsrv_query($link,$stmt); 
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
```

the 2nd line is consuming the first row from the array. Yes?

This advances a pointer in a buffer would be my guess (not a PHP person). Thus, the while() loop starts at row 2.